# Invalid object in JSon

Tags: json, c#-4.0

I was trying to learn json and applying knowledge in www.json.com into my c# test project and ran into some road blocks. Hope anyone experienced with json and c# outside could shed some light in my dark cave..:)
I have this text file representing json objects

```
[{
"STATES":"some state 1",
"STATE":[{"STATES":"null","ID":"id 1","func":"function1","update":"action1"},
         {"STATES":"null","ID":"id 2","func":"null","update":"null"}]
},
{
"STATES":"some state 2",
"STATE":[{"STATES":"null","ID":"id 1","func":"function1","update":"action2"},{"STATES":"null","ID":"id 2"}]
}]
```

I have a quick and dirty testing C# project

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace TestJson
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string text = File.ReadAllText("JsonTest.txt");
            JObject json = JObject.Parse(text);
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", text);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
     }
}
```

My goal is pretty simple and straight forward. Read a json from a text file and parse the json object. compiling is fine but when I tried to run it, I got a JSon exception error telling me that my objects are not JSon.

I have read the document from json.org and thought I understood the definition of objects, obviously, there is something I have missed. If anyone could point out the violation in definition of my json objects, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is not a JSON object, it's a JSON array. So you need to parse it with the *JArray* class:

```
JArray json = JArray .Parse(text);
```